# Identity elements of semirings

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid, semiring

When we define a [group](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Group.html) the identity element can be any suitable one. E.g.
$(\mathbb{N}, 0, +, -)$ or $(\mathbb{N}, 1, \cdot , N_i^{-1})$ are two groups with $2$ different identity elements.
Now it is not clear to me if in the definition of a [semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) when it is stated that the identity element is $0$ and $1$ if that is meant literary. I.e. that the identity elements of the two semirings have to be $0$ and $1$.
I am asking because when reading about groups, I encountered also some definitions that used $1$ to denote the identity element but in reality they meant $I_m$ (whatever is the Identity of the set $M$).
Could someone please confirm?

Comment: Typically $0$ denotes the identity for the addition operation and $1$ for multiplication.

Comment: @Berci: So it is not literary $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (semi)ring has 2 basic operations, the addition and the multiplication.

Independently, both are required to be associative and to have an identity element (so that they are *monoids*).

The identity element for addition is denoted by $0$, and the identity element for multiplication is denoted by $1$.

Comment: So it is just a notation and not literary the numbers $0$ and $1$? Could have been $I_a$ and $I_b$ i.e. to denote $2$ different identity elements (which ever they are)?

Comment: Have I understood your answer correctly? It is just a notation and not the literal numbers $0$ and $1$ right?

Comment: Yes, it's a notation only.

Answer (score 0):

The identity elements $0$ and $1$ in a semiring doesn't always mean the real numbers. For example, in case of a matrix semiring $M$, additive identity $0$ means zero matrix, while multiplicative identity $1$ means identity matrix, where the operations in $M$ is usual matrix addition and multiplication. Also another example is in max-plus semiring, additive identity is $0=$-$\infty$ and multiplicative identity is real number $1=0$. Probably, there is no known semiring in which additive identity is a real number $0$ and its corresponding multiplicative identity is real $1$.